# load posts from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i m working over application connected with fire base here which retrieves data from db 'm getting error unresolved reference dataSnapshot in Homefrag.kt file and to be very precise in 
 //load posts from firebase
    fun LoadPostFromFireBase(){...}

> clean project=>rebuild=>invalidate cache

fun LoadPostFromFireBase(){

```
    myRef.child("posts")
            .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {

                override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot  ) {

                    try {

                        listOfPost.clear()
                        listOfPost.add(Post("0","him","url"," ","add","addPost"))

                        var td= dataSnapshot!!.value as HashMap<String,Any>

                        for(key in td.keys){

                            var post= td[key] as HashMap<String,Any>

                            listOfPost.add(Post(key,
                                    post["postText"] as String,
                                    post["postImageURL"] as String
                                    ,post["postDate"] as String
                                    ,post["personName"] as String
                                    ,post["personID"] as String))


                        }


                        adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }catch (ex:Exception){}


                }

                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

                }
            })
}
```

getting unresolved dataSnapshot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for something that does not exist. Look at what the function onDataChange is giving you through its parameters.
I don't know Kotlin, but I'm pretty sure looking at your syntax that you're receiving "p0" inside the onDataChange, but you're looking for the object dataSnapshot.

You can fix it by replacing

```
var td= dataSnapshot!!.value as HashMap<String,Any>
```

with

```
var td= p0!!.value as HashMap<String,Any>
```